# What is the available ways to handle states in various models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an web app with RoR and it has various models. Each model will have various states, E.g.:

User - approved by admin, approved by government, rejected, suspended, blacklisted, owner, renter

Car - listed, hidden, approved, rejected, suspended.

I wonder what the best way is to handle the various states, of which some states are mutually exclusive and some can co-exist.

I know we can use 'state_machine' gem. But I wonder if there are any industry best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder what the best way is to handle the various states, of which
>   some states are mutually exclusive and some can co-exist.

If there's such situation, consider structuring your model in a way that you have multiple states columns. i.e. in your example, I can think of **User's** **state** (approved by admin, approved by government, rejected, suspended, blacklisted), and **type** (owner, renter).

As to managing states and different transitions between states, I recommend you to take a look at [workflow gem](https://github.com/geekq/workflow). Very flexible, clean and smart approach to managing states.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @thaold on the distinction between the User's state and its type. Be careful conflating attributes that are actually independent of each other (coexistence is a warning sign) - it can be very difficult to disentangle them later, especially when they're codified into a list together.

If you don't need/want a full state machine gem, I typically put these in modules as constants.

```
class User
  module State
    APPROVED_BY_ADMIN      = 'approved_by_admin'.freeze
    APPROVED_BY_GOVERNMENT = 'approved_by_government'.freeze
    # ...
  end

  module LivingSituation
    OWNER  = 'owner'.freeze
    RENTER = 'renter'.freeze
  end
end

class Car
  module State
    LISTED = 'listed'.freeze
    # ...
  end
end
```

Having them encapsulated lets you do some metaprogramming on `Car::State.constants` if you want to easily replicate parts of a state machine library like `Car#listed?`.